# Audio file conversion 0x0135 (Sipro Lab KELVIN)

Tags: audio, codec

I have an audio file of File type - WAVE (.WAV), Mime Type - audio/wav
Codec - 0x0135 (Sipro Lab KELVIN)

[image]

Is it possible to convert this file to Mp3? If so, can you please provide pointers.  Also, I'm not able to play this wav file in vlc player. Specific codec needs to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Looks difficult unless you can find a codec for Sipro Lab KELVIN format.**

Long Answer:

Most players rely on a system codec to decode the audio. So if you install the Sipro Lab Kelvin codec, then you will be able to play the audio in players, like Windows Media Player, that use underlying system codecs. If you can get such a codec, there is a complicated way to convert from any format to the MP3 format.

VLC, on the other hand, does not use codecs installed in the system. Based on [VLC audio support](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.php?cat=audio) page, VLC does not support codec type 0x135.

The other powerful codec tool ffmpeg also does not seem to support Sipro Lab Kelvin audio as per [FFMPEG audio codec support page](http://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Audio-Codecs).

Comment: One thing to add - please read https://www.ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html (particularly "submitting sample media"), file a feature request and provide a sample and link to the sample in your bug report. The reason I say this is that it looks like this is an acelp variant; ffmpeg already supports acelp, so there's a small possibility that a tweak to the ffmpeg decoders (by the developers) will make it work.